VS Code not able to find my python libraries when code runner's 'run in terminal' is checked on
I had to reinstall VS code a bit ago and that ended up breaking my ability to use libraries since it just returns a ModuleNotFoundError even if I have the library installed and even if I reinstall them. Libraries like sys, time, datetime, and socket work though. Installing the code runner extension fixed this by letting me use libraries again but I now cannot use inputs with code runner's output. Checking the run in terminal option allows input but I again cannot use my libraries.
Uninstalling code runner breaks the libraries but allows input. Run in terminal allows input but breaks libraries. I might just be missing something to install but I have no idea what that might be. Using 'run as python file' will return ModuleNotFoundError no matter what is turned on or installed.

You almost certainly have multiple installations of Python here.  What you need to do is tell VSCode to use the installation where you've installed your packages.

ModuleNotFound error was usually caused by incorrect python interpreter.
You can use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose the correct python interpreter which you installed the python package in.
You could also install the package in your current environment by command pip install packageName in the terminal.
